# can I write something to edit the /.kube/config file as soon as create a new cluster in terraform?

Tags: terraform, kubectl, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks, hcl

```js
provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster.endpoint
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster.certificate_authority.0.data)
  token                  = data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.cluster.token
  config_path = local.kubectl_config_path
  config_context =  data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster.arn
}
##################################################################


data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {
}

locals {
  cluster_name = "Cluster-${random_string.suffix.result}"
  kubectl_config_path = "C:/Users/User/.kube/config"
}
```

I want to get access to the cluster
without editing Infos in the config file myself.

wondering if I can do this only with terraform
or is there any other way?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to provide

```
  config_path = local.kubectl_config_path
  config_context =  data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster.arn
```

when you have provided `host`, `cluster_ca_certificate` and `token`. So no need to write to local kubeconfig file to get access to the cluster for the terraform kubernetes provider to work.

If you want to replace the current local kubeconfig file to run `kubectl` commands manually, you can write the kubeconfig via a null-resource.local-exec` [reference](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec.html#interpreter-examples)